# Insert annotation view fails in iOS 11.0.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mapkit

I released an app to App Store some days ago, and today I went to check if there were any crashes. I found out that on two different devices, I had the same crash, related to **MKSpatialCollider's insertAnnotationView**. Both devices mount iOS 11.0.3.
I use MapKit in a ViewController to display custom AnnotationView objects, that I also group in clusters, that's all. I have no idea about these crashes, what could be happening in my app that triggers these events?
Below, I attached those two exceptions' stacktraces, but if you need something else to figure out what's happening, just let me know:

**First exception's stacktrace**

[image]

**Second  exception's stacktrace**

[image]

Update 1 - Here's the link to the code that should trigger the errors (I'm not sure since Xcode points to another file that doesn't contain MapKit at all): https://gist.github.com/MrOverflOOw/bbc14d546ef10bd17065af08fdf3e27c

Comment: You can track these crashes in  Xcode > Organizer , which let you in code where its happing.

Comment: Yes, that's the place where I found these stacktraces I uploaded! But in Xcode, if I try to click on the stacktrace, it points me to a line that shouldn't be involved at all...

Comment: can you share some code where its happened?

Comment: post updated: see that link!

Comment: I'm getting this on iOS 12 too.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who's still searching for an answer to a similar problem: in my case, if a **user press the back button while annotations are being added to MapView, my app throws the exception above**.
From here (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92799), it seems to be an **iOS 11 related problem**: Apple should release an update soon.
If anyone has further information or a workaround to solve the problem for the meantime, please share it here: I have been able to **solve it** **displaying an ActivityIndicator until MapKit completes adding annotations**.

Comment: I tried these solutions and none of them had any affect. Only when I turned off animating into a map rect: mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: false) did this fix the issue see below last answer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when attempting to remove an instance of MKClusterAnnotation from the map views annotations. Specifically when a annotation view is reused for an MKClusterAnnotation. Check to see if you do anything like:

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

or if you're in Swift:

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

or really any line of code where you might muck with an MKClusterAnnotation provided by MapKit.

Comment: Oddly it seems like MKClusterAnnotation instances pile up in the `annotation` property of MKMapView. I ran into this while trying to manually clean them up.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?

Comment: @Genki Ultimately, we opted for our own clustering logic unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that worked for me was to deselect annotations (cluster ones are the problem) before adding or removing any other annotations.

I realize your case may not involve adding or removing annotations, but my app crashes in the same MKSpatialCollider code path, so thought I'd mention this workaround. You might try deselecting annotations before the view goes away.

Comment: I tried deslecting by only turning off animations into a visible maprect did it fix the problem mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: false)

Comment: Had a similar stack trace to the first screenshot in the OP and fixed it by deselecting all selected annotations in my view controller's `deinit`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution although I tried all the answers listed above and I still got the crash.

[image: When tapping on IOS 11 MKClusterView with animation on this crash happened consistently]

[image: When tapping on IOS 11 MKClusterView with animation on this crash happened consistently]

However when I set zooming to FALSE the crash stops happening completely!? Why? I want to zoom in it looks nice:

```
mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: false)
```

This is from this function (in which i am also deselecting the Cluster Annotations as suggested above):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    lastTouchedAtCoordinate = view.annotation?.coordinate
    guard let annotation = view.annotation else { return }

    if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
        var zoomRect = MKMapRectNull
        for annotation in cluster.memberAnnotations {
            self.mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
            let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)

            let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0)

            if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
                zoomRect = pointRect
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect)
            }
        }
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: true)

    }
}
```

This stopped the crash. I do not know why. I am loading and adding annotations a lot, but I made sure the user cannot interact with the map (as suggested above) by using a progress loader to dim out the background.

I am not using any threading and everything UI is done on the main thread (like adding annotations)

This is the stack trace from the phone, as you can see the system is removing the annotations (I am not at all as also suggested above), is this an apple bug? Or am I doing something wrong?:

> Model:      iPhone8,1 Process:
>   Path:
>   1.1 (1.0) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Role:                Foreground Parent Process:      launchd [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv9d2.png) Coalition:
>
> Date/Time:           2018-02-14 17:38:15.3949 +0100 Launch Time:
>   2018-02-14 17:37:10.1854 +0100 OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5
>   (15D60) Baseband Version:    4.30.02 Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000298 VM Region Info: 0x298 is
>   not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4328635752
>         REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
>         UNUSED SPACE AT START
>   --->
>         __TEXT                 000000010201c000-00000001022a0000 [ 2576K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...eDiveAdvisor]
>
> Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason:
>   Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   MapKit                           0x000000019650d190
>   -[MKSpatialCollider insertAnnotationView:] + 244 1   MapKit                           0x00000001964791b8 -[MKNewAnnotationContainerView
>   _updateClusterableAnnotationViews:withID:] + 456 2   MapKit                           0x00000001964791b8 -[MKNewAnnotationContainerView
>   _updateClusterableAnnotationViews:withID:] + 456 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000185dc51c0 -[__NSDictionaryM
>   enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 232 4   MapKit
>     0x0000000196479d58 -[MKNewAnnotationContainerView
>   updateAnnotationViewsForReason:] + 296 5   MapKit
>     0x0000000196549690 -[MKAnnotationContainerView
>   finishRemovingAnnotationViews] + 32 6   MapKit
>     0x00000001963c56dc -[MKAnnotationManager updateVisibleAnnotations] +
>   1616 7   MapKit                           0x00000001963c5064
>   -[MKAnnotationManager deselectAnnotation:animated:] + 376 8   MapKit                          0x00000001963e4198 -[MKAnnotationManager
>   _removeAnnotation:updateVisible:removeFromContainer:] + 468 9   MapKit                            0x00000001964029ac -[MKMapView removeAnnotation:] + 100 10  MapKit
>     0x00000001964010b8 -[MKMapView
>   annotationContainer:requestRemovingClusterAnnotationView:] + 60 11 
>   MapKit                            0x0000000196479f8c
>   __73-[MKNewAnnotationContainerView _updateClusterableAnnotationViews:withID:]_block_invoke + 84 12  MapKit                            0x00000001964ac108
>   __49-[MKAnnotationView _performHideAnimationIfNeeded]_block_invoke.208 + 232 13  UIKit                            0x000000018f4ea188 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 764 14  UIKit                          0x000000018f4e9afc -[UIViewAnimationState
>   sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312 15  UIKit
>     0x000000018f4e9808 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
>   + 296 16  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189f4adc4 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks+ 1252804 (void*) + 284 17 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x0000000185876a14
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {  
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)  
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)  
}
```

Seems to fix the crash for me